# fix database wrong encoded

Tags: mysql

I have an old site that the encoding is **utf8**. But the database is **latin1**. The problem is that all data (thousands) were recorded wrong.

Sample of a phrase engraved

> verificaÃ§Ã£o de erro na geraÃ§Ã£o dos cÃ³digos

Is there any SQL function that transforms all records in the database for the correct coding?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is simple :)

```
INSERT INTO utf8table (utf8column)
    SELECT CONVERT(latin1field USING utf8) FROM latin1table;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html

You can also do that with PHP. You can select data, transform it with iconv() functions, and update appropriate fields. Do whaterver you are more confortable with.

Comment: The convert function did not work because the information database has already been written in error. Then I try another way. Thank's

Comment: If you have missing/truncated/damaged data, It'll really take more than my solution.